# Flutter Form Builder fields, how to initialize as dirty state

Tags: flutter-form-builder

I am using Flutter Form Builder fields in my application.
We have a "resilient" user experience, in that the application can be closed and re-opened, and your state will be restored as if you never left.

This includes, if you are editing a field so it's considered "dirty" (i.e., current value does not match initialValue) - this 'dirtiness state' will also be restored.

How can one achieve this at a field level?
I do have a POC working(ish) - but it's having some consistency issues.

Please, can it be done without passing the rehydrated state to the FormBuilder constructor - because the widget in our app which hosts the FormBuilder is much higher up in the tree...

What would an ideal scenario look like?

```
FormBuilderDropdown(
  initialValue: null,
  currentValue: 'restored value' // but this only affects the initial state of the dropdown...
)
```

At the moment my 'hack' is calling a variety of `FormBuilderState.setInternalFieldValue` and `FormBuilderFieldState.setValue` - but it seems to work for simple text fields and switches, but not dropdowns